# Get device orientation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I feel like I can vastly improve this. Any ideas?

```
// get orientation of device
getOrientation();

// animate
var num = 400;

if( $('body').hasClass("landscape") ) {
    $('.example').animate({'bottom', 0});
} else {
    $('.example').animate({'bottom', num});
}


function getOrientation(){

    switch(window.orientation) {  
     case -90:
     case 90:
    $('body').addClass("landscape");
        // alert('landscape');
        break; 
     default:
       //alert('portrait');
       $('body').addClass("portrait");
       break; 
     }
}

window.onorientationchange = function() {
  getOrientation();
};
```

Comment: I think that your `window.onorientationchange` will never trigger any change.

Answer (score 2):

Well for starters bind the event using the jQuery standard

```
var $win = $(window).bind('orientationchange', function(){
    // math.abs to reduce logical operators   
    $('body').removeClass('landscape portrait') // reset
        .addClass(Math.abs(this.orientation) === 90 ? "landscape" : "portrait");     
});

// now you can trigger the orientation manually on doc ready to set the class
$win.trigger('orientationchange');

var num = 400,
    $body = $('body'),
    $example = $('.example');

if($body.hasClass("landscape"))
    $example.animate({'bottom', 0});
else
    $example.animate({'bottom', num});
```

Comment: Thanks for this! What is different between binding the event and how I originally had it?

Comment: There are several benefits adding events using addEventListener vs just assigning a property. For example you can add many listeners instead of just one, etc. But additionally jQuery normalizes the event arg0 passed into the handler so that events behave the same across browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Use ternary operators, something like:

```
 // get orientation of device
getOrientation();

// animate
var num = 400;

$('.example').animate({'bottom', $('body').hasClass("landscape") ? 0 : num});

function getOrientation(){
    $('body').removeAttr('class'); //Removing all classes
    $('body').addClass(90===Math.abs(window.orientation) ? "landscape" : "portrait");
}

window.onorientationchange = function() {
  getOrientation();
};
```